# Bootstrap carousel. Add pagination dots to bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would it be possible to add pagination as in dots to the existing carousel for bootstrap.

It needs to move automatically through the dots.

Very new to this and need a little hand.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdesignone/qXgCg/

Thanks:)

Answer (score 10):

This feature is currently [slated to be included in the 2.3 milestone](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1993) (currently at 2.1).  There is presently a [pull request](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2777) which already implements this functionality, and I would recommend using it rather than rolling your own, as it is more likely to be consistent with the final API once the feature gets integrated officially.

The source for the plugin can be found in [mikaelbr's fork of the Bootstrap project](https://github.com/mikaelbr/bootstrap/blob/1993/js/bootstrap-carousel.js).  You will require both the **bootstrap-carousel.js** and the **carousel.less**.

Here is a demo:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/fSGnG/)

Comment: Just want to update and say (for any visitor that does not know) that Bootstrap 2.3 is out as of this morning.

Answer (score 6):

With latest carousel, you can use **carousel-indicators** class:

```
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: I think this question was about TB 2.x, the carousel-indicators only work in 3.x

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat hacky way of doing it, as I had to do this as well for my site.
Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qXgCg/2/

```
//Javascript   
var slider = $(".carousel-inner") 
.carousel({ interval: 5000 }) 
.bind('slid', function() { 
var index = $(this).find(".active").index(); 
$(this).find("a").removeClass('pager-active').eq(index).addClass('pager-active'); 
}); 

$(".slider-pager a").click(function(e){ 
  var index = $(this).index(); 
  slider.carousel(index); 
  e.preventDefault(); 
}); 

/* css */
.slider-pager        {    margin-top: 10px; }
.slider-pager a    {    display: block; height: 10px; width: 10px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; border-radius: 50%; background: #41af96; font-size: 1px; color: #fff; text-indent: -9999px; }
.slider-pager a.pager-active { background: #2c8571; }

<!--html --->
<div class="slider-pager">
<a href="#main-slider" class="pager-active">0</a>
<a href="#main-slider">1</a>
<a href="#main-slider">2</a>
</div>
```