# adding bullets to a slider on "customizr" wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress-theming

I have very little experience with the jquery libraries. I need to remove the arrows from the main slider and add bullets at the bottom(bullets to navigate the slides). Any one proficient with java script please guide me how to do it. [Customizr](http://wordpress.org/themes/customizr) is a free theme in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customizr has been build on Twitter's Bootstrap 2. Also the slider is based on a Bootstrap's component, see: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel.

In Bootstrap 2.x the carsousel does not offer support for indication of the total number of items in the carousel and the current position of the carousel. See also: [Bootstrap carousel. Add pagination dots to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271827/bootstrap-carousel-add-pagination-dots-to-bottom).

This function is add in Twitter's Bootstrap 3.x, see: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel.

So to fix your problem, use the solution described here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1993 or find a Theme ready for Twitter's Bootstrap 3 like [Roots](http://www.roots.io) or [JBST](https://github.com/bassjobsen/jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme). The [Twitter Bootstrap Slider](http://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter-bootstrap-slider/) also provides Bootstrap's carousel function to WordPress.